# Another program crash on vector.push_back()

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program that reads in data from text files, sorts the data in various ways and then uses the sorted data for other calculations. Let me say that in `int main(){ }` there is one large for-loop that contains many other for-loops and that the segment of code that I am posting is just one of those many for-loops inside the main one.

```
 for(t=(compare.t - 1000)*2 - 12 ;t< ( (compare.t - 1000)*2 + 12 /);t++){

  rank.push_back(vector <int>() );p++;


     for(ii=111;ii<2489;ii++){
          if(M_screened[a][ii].size()>0){

             if( fabs(M_screened[a][ii][0].t-(t*0.5 + 1000.0)) <0.257 ){
                  cout<<"ii = "<<ii<<" t = "<<t<<"  sizeof(rank) = "<<rank.size()<<"  p = "<<p;
                  cout<<"   rank["<<p<<"].size() = "<<rank[p].size()<<endl;
                  cout<<"   "<<endl;
                  cout<<"address = "<<&rank[p][rank[p].size()-1];
                  rank[p].push_back(ii);
                  cout<<" "<<endl;
              }
          }
      }       
 foutT<<t*0.5 + 1000<<" "<<frequency[a][t]<<endl;} //end t-loop
```

All of the `cout` statements were just part of my own error checking process. Also, the large for-loop that contains the above code segment is able to run 2 iterations prior to crashing on the third (every single time).

Basically what I've narrowed it down to is crashing on the push_back() function. Parameter values at the time of crash:

```
t=177, p = 10, ii = 873, sizeof(rank) = 11, rank[10].size() = 1
```

Here is the error message I get from Microsoft Visual Studio :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0000000077993290 (ntdll.dll) in Muon_fitting7_7_2014_statistics.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000038085FFA1E8.
```

If I can provide any additional information please let me know.

Comment: Hey Dan, I've done what you suggested and it works just fine in other instances - I have this same code performing in slightly different versions. The difference in this version is that large for-loop containing everything that I mentioned earlier, in other versions its a while-loop that holds everything. Also, I inserted cout statements before and after the rank[p].push_back(ii) statement to verify that it does crash precisely right there.

Comment: Hey Dan, in the list of parameters I provide you can see that the indices are correct. Also, it is the 177th iteration of the for-loop using variable t and many other rank vectors have been created without fault in the same way. I would be glad to simplify the code to a very basic example if you would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you've initialized P to zero or some such thing when declared and that is actually your problem.

```
for(t=(compare.t - 1000)*2 - 12 ;t< ( (compare.t - 1000)*2 + 12 /);t++)
{
    rank.push_back(vector <int>() );p++;
    for(ii=111;ii<2489;ii++)
    {
        if(M_screened[a][ii].size()>0){
            if( fabs(M_screened[a][ii][0].t-(t*0.5 + 1000.0)) <0.257 ){
              rank[p].push_back(ii);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

At first, rank has no elements, then you push back and increment p.   Now rank as 1 element but you need to use rank[p-1] to access it as p is already 1.   That or initialize p to -1 to start so when you increment it, its at zero.    Vector [] access is zero based.

So, try this :

```
int p = -1;
for(t = ((compare.t - 1000)*2 - 12);t < ((compare.t - 1000)*2 + 12);++t)
{
    rank.push_back(vector <int>() );
    ++p;
    for(ii=111;ii<2489;++ii)
    {
        if (M_screened[a][ii].size() > 0)
        {
            if (fabs(M_screened[a][ii][0].t-(t*0.5 + 1000.0)) < 0.257)
            {
                rank[p].push_back(ii);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```